# mononotone and pseudomonotone operators in current research

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples, boundary-value-problem

I know that the following question is quite broad for this forum. But I am interested in references or any other ideas. Can anyone provide some examples of applications of monotone or pseudomonotone operators in mathematics or applied science in current research. I am aware of the use in proving the existence of solutions to nonlinear elliptic boundary value problems but I am interested in further more current research.

Thanks a lot for any assistance.